# Rails 4 eager loading has_one and belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, eager-loading, belongs-to, has-one

I have a model Vendor with association:

```
has_one :school, foreign_key: "school_vendor_id"
```

I have a model School with association:

```
belongs_to :vendor, foreign_key: "school_vendor_id"
```

I have done eager loading:

```
@vendors = Vendor.includes(:school).where(:business_id=>@business.id)
```

My problem is in views.

```
<% @vendors.each do |v| %><br/>
<%= v.vendor_name %><br/>
**<%= v.school.id %>**   //Gives an error
undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
```

If I do `<%= v.school.inspect %>`, I get the following result

```
#<School id: 1, school_vendor_id: 1.................
```

I can't figure out how to display the school record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you've got a vendor that doesn't have an associated school.

So `v.school` returns nil and `v.school.id` raises an error for **a particular** vendor.

Your `v.school.inspect` is returning a school because it's for **some other** vendor.

To fix this, use `v.school.try(:id) || 'No associated school'` in your view. Then in your view, you'll be able to see which vendors don't have schools.

You could also do the following in your Rails Console to see which vendors don't have schools.

```
Vendor.where("id NOT IN (?)", School.pluck(:vendor_id))
```